# IDX workbench dialog page can't be resized

Tags: vlocity, tools

IDX workbench dialog page can't be resized. I used ctrl - to make it small for bottom button, but can't bring it back by ctrl +. Any resize, move will make the application frozen. I had to kill the process. Reinstallation the application does not help. Not sure where the dialog page info stored.

I can't use the tool anymore because front, fields are so small on any configuration dialog box. How can I fix the issue?

Please help.